# How to protect some rows and other rows are non protect and able to delete rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have one issue, i want to protect the sheet, but delete permission will be given to the user.
But upto 9 rows are hidden, these rows should not be deleted. Is there any possibility.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this in plain standard Excel or in Excel-VBA macro language?

Comment: I need to protect through VBA code. Excel VBA

Comment: Provide the user with a button to delete selected rows. In the macro, unprotect/delete/reprotect, and checking each selected row to see whether it's one of your hidden rows.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your response. Any other way, without putting button. not interested to put a button on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I just tested this and it seems to get at what you want.

- Unlock cells in all rows that will not be hidden.
- Keep all rows that are to be hidden locked
- Hide the rows
- Protect the worksheet with the following priviliges:
         Select Unlocked cells
         Delete Rows
         (whatever else you wish to give them)

In this way, a user will not be able to select the hidden rows because they are locked. However, if a user wants to delete rows above / below the hidden ones, they will have to use Ctrl + Mouse Click to select the separate ranges.

Also, with this solution. You don't even need VBA. You just have to set it up before you protect the sheet, than add the protection.